# Capturing product impression without making the website slow

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intersection-observer

I am working on a website where we have thousands of products. I have to capture the impression of all products users can see in their viewport. So I created a `directory` and I used `IntersectionObserver`, and referred to it inside the `HTML` code of that product. The issue is that it's causing a performing impact on the mobile site as soon as the user scrolls. How can I capture impressions without slowing my website?

```
export class IntersectionObserverDirective
  implements OnDestroy, OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() debounceTime = 0;
  @Input() threshold = 1;

  @Output() visible = new EventEmitter<HTMLElement>();
  isSSR: boolean = typeof window === 'undefined';

  private observer: IntersectionObserver | undefined;
  private subject$ = new Subject<{
    entry: IntersectionObserverEntry;
    observer: IntersectionObserver;
  }>();

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.createObserver();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.startObservingElements();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.observer) {
        this.observer.disconnect();
        this.observer = undefined;
      }
  
      this.subject$.next();
      this.subject$.complete();  
  }

  private isVisible(element: HTMLElement) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
        resolve(entry.intersectionRatio === 1);
        observer.disconnect();
      });

      observer.observe(element);
    });
  }

  private createObserver() {
    const options = {
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: this.threshold,
    };

    const isIntersecting = (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry) =>
      entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0;

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (isIntersecting(entry)) {
          this.subject$.next({ entry, observer });
        }
      });
    }, options);
  }

  private startObservingElements() {
    if (!this.observer) {
      return;
    }

    this.observer.observe(this.element.nativeElement);

    this.subject$
      .pipe(delay(this.debounceTime), filter(Boolean))
      .subscribe(async ({ entry, observer }) => {
        const target = entry.target as HTMLElement;
        const isStillVisible = await this.isVisible(target);

        if (isStillVisible) {
          this.visible.emit(target);
          observer.unobserve(target);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: Are you using pagination when loading your data from server? And if so, how many products are you loading on 1 page?

Comment: What code is running in the observer's callback function?

Comment: How are you storing those "impressions" ? are you calling an API each time a product is view ? are you interested in user that re-visited a product that you have already taken note as being visisted ? have you consider having a service that keeps the impressions, and every once in a while sends a batch of them to the backend ?

Comment: I have added the logic I use to track impression. I am storing all the impressions in an object. And we send it as an event. And every 5 second if we have any event data, we trigger an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a timeout in `createObserver()`. Something like this.

```
private createObserver() {
        const options = {
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: this.threshold,
        };
        let timeouts = {};
        const isIntersecting = (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry) =>
            entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0;
        this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (isIntersecting(entry)) {
                    timeouts[entry.target.id] = setTimeout(() => {
                        this.subject.next({ entry, observer });
                    }, 500);
                }
                else {
                    clearTimeout(timeouts[entry.target.id])
                }
            });
        }, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has robust scroll triggers, among a host of other tools. You should delegate the tracking to a party which has experience. GA is more standard, it has more value to a client, and you will learn more about users.

If you hate Google and must invent your own tool from the ground up, go ahead and don't. The scroll and cursor fire off thousands of events a second and they bubble to multiple elements. Use GA for your clicks and heatmaps!